# Making download links out of all of the files in a particular folder

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Right now there is an upload system on the site I am working on where users can upload some documents to a particular file. Later on I will need to make these documents downloadable. Is there an easy way to iterate through all the files in a particular directory and create download links for the files?

Something like:

```
foreach($file){
   echo '<a href=""'somepath/'.$file.'">somefilename</a>';
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($dh = opendir('path/to/directory')) {
    while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if($file == "." || $file == "..") { continue; }
        echo '<a href="path/to/directory/' . $file . '">' . $file . '</a>';
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
```

Comment: +1, Exactly what I wanted, thank you very much, clear and useful example!

Answer (score 0):

You should see [`opendir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php).

Example from that page adapted to question:

```
$dir = "/etc/php5/";

$path = "/webpath";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
      while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
          echo "<a href=\"$webpath/$file\">$file</a>";
      }
      closedir($dh);
  }
}
```